# In C++,if the Base class constructor exception,then the sequence of constructor and destructor could be this?

Tags: c++, exception, constructor

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Base
{
public:
    Base()
    {
        cout << "Base"<<endl;
    }
    ~Base()
    {
        cout << "~Base"<<endl;
    }

};

class Child: public Base
{
public:
    Child()
    {
        cout << "Child"<<endl;
    }
    ~Child()
    {
        cout << "~Child"<<endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    try
    {
        Child cc;
    }
    catch(...)
    {
    }

    return 0;
}
```

the general output will be

```
Base 
Child
~Child
~Base
```

But if something terrible or exception caught while Base is constructor ,then is 
it possible that the sequece will be :

```
Base 
~Base
Child
~Child
```

Can anyone write a demo to illustate this? C++ usually doesn't throw exception in the constuctor, but if it does, then could it leads to that output?

Thanks for all helping.
I am not sure that in usually code ,this could happens. Is it possible in complicated Base constructor or something wrong or whatever,that will change the usual output ?
   If so, can anyone give me one example?

Comment: why can't you "write a demo to illustrate this" yourself?

Comment: I write some test code, but it seems C++ doesn't support stack rescroll, after got exception, the desctructor will not be called.

Comment: I write some test code, but after caught exception, the destructor will not be called. Is there a way to illustrate that if something wrong or exception happens while at constuctor Base , the output will be Base() ~Base() Child() ~Child().

Answer (score 4):

If a exception occurs in your `Base` class constructor no destructors are called.
Simply because there is no complete object that needs to be destroyed!

Can't help but **[quote Herb on this](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/066.htm)**:

### "It cannot die, for it never lived!"

Answer (score 0):

```
include <stdexcept>
Base()
{
    cout << "Base"<<endl;
    throw std::runtime_error("error");
}
```

Comment: He just wanted a test for it so he can find out himself experimentally

Comment: I tried you way, it seems that after B constructor calls, no other will be called.